# `FlatList` with a `CellRendererComponent` implementation does not show all items on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, cellrenderer

We have a component for a sortable list that uses `FlatList` with a `CellRendererComponent`:

```
<FlatList
  ...
  data={data}
  CellRendererComponent={SortableListItem}
/>
```

We have a usage where on some Android devices, at least part of the time only the start of the list is shown, and the end is cut.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with `FlatList` (it reproduced with a simpler example), a workaround for short lists it to add:

```
initialNumToRender={data.length}
```